# equation labels for reference

Tags: equations

How can I reference to the equations in the `alignat`? The equation set is

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
 \sigma_1 &= x + y  &\quad \sigma_2 &= \frac{x}{y} \\  
 \sigma_1' &= \frac{\partial x + y}{\partial x} & \sigma_2'
    &= \frac{\partial \frac{x}{y}}{\partial x}
\end{alignat}
```

Now in my text I want to refer like this

```
As you can see, \ref{equation1} is above \ref{equation2}!
```

Comment: Add a unique `\label{}` to each line of the equation.

Comment: qnd you may want to use `\eqref` instead of just `\ref`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We would use `\label{labelname}` on a line (before the `\\` command) to label a particular line. It is conventional to use the `\eqref` command in order to automatically wrap the reference with parentheses.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
\sigma_1 &= x + y  &\quad \sigma_2 &= \frac{x}{y} \label{equation1}\\  
\sigma_1' &= \frac{\partial x + y}{\partial x} & \sigma_2'
     &= \frac{\partial \frac{x}{y}}{\partial x} \label{equation2}
\end{alignat}

As you can see, \eqref{equation1} is above \eqref{equation2}!
\end{document}
```

Since labels are not 'typed', it is also conventional to precede the label by `eq:` in order to indicate the label is an equation label. For example, we would use `\label{eq:equation1}` and `\eqref{eq:equation1}` or something to that effect.